# read function skipping backwards 4086 bytes instead of 6 bytes forward in file

Tags: c, linux, file, io, fread

I have a truly strange problem on my hand. I am reading a file and run a fread, and instead of skipping ahead by the 6 bytes like it should, it goes backwards 4092-6 bytes!

Here is the call:

```
int bread = sizeof(RoughnessReadPoint) * fread(&roughnessBuffer, sizeof(RoughnessReadPoint), 1, ptr);
```

Here is the associated struct:

```
struct RoughnessReadPoint
{
   S8 x;
   S8 y;
   S8 z;
   S8 x2;
   S8 y2;
   S8 z2;
};
```

Here is a GDB trace showing the read:

```
216         int bread = sizeof(RoughnessReadPoint) * fread(&roughnessBuffer, sizeof(RoughnessReadPoint), 1, ptr);
(gdb) p ptr->_IO_read_ptr
$5 = 0x5555557cce42 "\002\017\374\016\002\373˱N\001\002\017\374\017\020\020"
(gdb) n
217             totalBytesRead += bread;
(gdb) p ptr->_IO_read_ptr
$6 = 0x5555557cce48 "˱N\001\002\017\374\017\020\020"
```

As you can see it jumps by 6 as its supposed to.

Now the problem section:

```
216         int bread = sizeof(RoughnessReadPoint) * fread(&roughnessBuffer, sizeof(RoughnessReadPoint), 1, ptr);
(gdb) p ptr->_IO_read_ptr
$14 = 0x5555557cce4c "\002\017\374\017\020\020"
(gdb) n
217             totalBytesRead += bread;
(gdb) p ptr->_IO_read_ptr
$15 = 0x5555557cbe52 "\261N\001\002\017\374\017\002\374ͱN\001\002\017\373\017\002\374бN\001\002\017\374\017\002\373ұN\001\002\017\373\016\002\373ձN\001\002\017\373\016\002\373ױN\001\002\017\374\016\002\373ڱN\001\002\017\373\016\002\373ܱN\001\002\017\373\017\002\373߱N\001\002\017\373\017\002\373\342\261N\001\002\017\373\017\002\374\344\261N\001\002\017\373\017\002\373\347\261N\001\002\017\373\017\002\373\351\261N\001\002\017\373\017\002\373\354\261N\001\002\017\373\017\002\373\356\261N\001\002\017\374\016\002\373\361\261N\001\002\017\373\016\002\373\363\261N\001\002\017\374\016\002\373\366\261N\001\002\017\374\016\002\373\370\261N\001\002\017\374\016\002\373\373\261N\001\002\017\374\016\002\373", <incomplete sequence \375>...
```

Notice, the read pointer went **BACKWARDS** 4086 bytes.

For good measure, I printed out how many bytes were read here as well...

```
(gdb) p bread
$16 = 6
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

Other information: 
This is obviously a debug build, but it happens when compiling with -O2 as well
This is ubuntu 18.04 compiled with g++
The file is about 130MB long and this happens at about 83MB into the file

If I keep reading, the file gets close to the same point over and over again only to fall back 4086 bytes every time!

Comment: The fields of a `FILE` aren't mean to be read by users of the library.  Instead, call `ftell` to get the current file offset and use it to verify that you're at the position you want to be at.

Comment: You are assuming that the `_IO_read_ptr` is tracking a contiguous block of virtual memory. That may not be so. That's internal implementation and unless you have gone into the source code of `fread` to see what it is really doing you should not make such assumptions.

Comment: You are correct. Using ftell does produce the correct (expected) file offset. Thanks, I found a problem with the file I was reading. Oddly enough it just happens to occur at the same byte read the _IO_read_ptr jumps.

Answer (score 1):

As dbush and kaylum said in the comments, I should have used ftell as opposed to using the internal variables in the FILE struct. My issue was with the file I was reading - it just happened to occur at the same point the internal variable jumped.